# How to cache a specific portion of a UIMapView

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, mkmapview

I'd like to have the imagery of a UIMapView for a whole city cached and shipped with my app to have the user actually see a map when they are offline.

Is there a way to do this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is technically possible (you'd use Google's map API rather than using a specific iOS API) it's actually against the T&C's of the service. There are a few apps that use [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) for this purpose. It has the CC-BY-SA licence.

Comment: I'll give OpenStreetMaps a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not within [Google's terms of service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/iphone/terms.html). See section 10.3.